How to add Google Ads Manager Ads units (Banners) using NuxtJs/VueJs frameworks?
I have this Ads unit

<script type="text/javascript">
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-2158343444694791";/* AD7 */
google_ad_slot = "AD7";
google_ad_width = 300;
google_ad_height = 250;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"></script>

The website is developed using NodeJs, NuxtJs3, and VueJs3 with both SSR and SPA. I would like to place a script on my website's homepage to show the banner 5 times in different places. However, I can not place script tags inside the vuejs template. Can you please guide me on how to render this correctly?
So far, I have attempted the following:
Template
<div class="my_div"></div>

Javascript

nuxt.hook("page:loading:end", () => {
  loaderLoading.value = false
  setTimeout(() => {
    var div = document.querySelector('.my_div');

    // Create a script element
    var script = document.createElement('script');

    // Set the type attribute
    script.type = 'text/javascript';

    // Set the source (src) attribute
    script.src = '//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js';

    // Create an inline script element for the ad parameters
    var inlineScript = document.createElement('script');
    inlineScript.type = 'text/javascript';
    inlineScript.innerHTML = `
    google_ad_client = "ca-pub-2158343444694791";
    /* AD7 */
    google_ad_slot = "AD7";
    google_ad_width = 300;
    google_ad_height = 250;
`;
    console.log("test")
    // Append the inline script to the div
    div.appendChild(inlineScript);

    // Append the script to the div
    div.appendChild(script);

  }, 2000);
}) 

This yields a lot of console errors such as :
Uncaught TagError: adsbygoogle.push() error: Ad client is missing from the slot.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild')
Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.

Please advise me on the correct placement of the ad units. Is there a library that supports Google Ads Manager ad units? Please note that this is different from Google AdSense.
Regards

Did you, by any chance, forget to add the rest of your template?

I did add a compleat template tags... No worries about that.

I used this Lib, problem solved!
https://github.com/pchynoweth/google-adsense-module
Thanks!

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
